# Assign Child's method to parent element in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

I'm creating an app with React and React Router, I'm starting with react.

I have this parent class:

```
class Home extends React.Component{

  checkLogin(){
    /*any logic..*/
  }
  /**
  * La funcion render es obligatoria en cualquier componente React.
  */

  render(){

    this.checkLogin();
    return(

        <div>
        <div className="body">
            <div className="all-container">
                <main className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <Imagen src="/images/foodie.png" className="img-responsive logo" alt="Foodie" />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {this.props.children}
                </main>
                <div className="separador-footer"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    );
  }

}
```

And this child "Login" class

```
class Login extends React.Component{

  iniciarSesion(){
      /*The login logic method */
  }

  render(){

    return (
        <form action="#">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">

                    <InputControl type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" id="username"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a" id="password"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <ul className="list-unstyled lista-links">
                        <li>
                            <Link to={Rutas.cambioClave}>Olvido su contrase&ntilde;a</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to={Rutas.registro}> Crear nueva Cuenta</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

             <BtnLink onClick={()=>this.iniciarSesion()} label="Iniciar Sesi&oacute;n"/>
        </form>
    );
  }
}
```

The thing is, I need to create another 3 or 4 "child components" with the same "template" and on each component I need a `BtnLink` component that will need to call the own child logic method (as "login", "register", "logout"). For this reason, I think it is better to put this `BtnLink` Component in the parent component and not repeat the code. Then, when the route changes and with that change the child component modifies the `BtnLink` component and changes its `onClick` method to dynamically add the current Child Component method that I may need. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If a button is the only thing that is common, I think that the simplest solution would just be to include one in each component. The rest of my answer is more relevant when there are more common components, but it can still be used here.

Instead of trying to manipulate the button through the parent component, I would create a `<ControlledForm>` (or whatever name you would like) component that has common parts (such as the `<BtnLink>` that you mentioned), but is otherwise customizable.

```js
const ControlledForm = (props) => (
  <form action={props.action}>
    {props.children}
    <BtnLink onClick={props.onClick} label={props.label}
  </form>
)
```

Which props you need to provide will be determined by what information you need to control.

For example, with the above `<ControlledForm>`, you could recreate your above `<Login>` component as follows:

```js
class Login extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.iniciarSesion = this.iniciarSesion.bind(this)
  }    

  iniciarSesion(){
    /*The login logic method */
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ControlledForm
        onClick={() => this.iniciarSesion()}
        label='Iniciar Sesi&oacute;n'
        action='#'
        >
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <InputControl type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" id="username"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a" id="password"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
            <ul className="list-unstyled lista-links">
              <li>
                <Link to={Rutas.cambioClave}>Olvido su contrase&ntilde;a</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to={Rutas.registro}> Crear nueva Cuenta</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ControlledForm>
    );
  }
}
```